# Analytical value of minima of a function involving Logarithm and exponential

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am trying to derive the analytical expression for the point of minima of the function
$$\frac{c+ x \ln(-2+2 e^{c/x})-\ln (-1+e^{2c/x})}{x [\ln(-1+e^{c/x})-\ln (-1+e^{2c/x}) ]} $$
Here $x$ is the variable and $c$ is a constant. Plot of the function for a specific $c$ value is shown in the figure:
[image]
Mathematica code:

```
(c + x (Log[-2 + 2 E^(c/x)] - 
Log[-1 + E^((2 c)/x)]))/(x (Log[-1 + E^(c/x)] - 
Log[-1 + E^((2 c)/x)]))
```

Any help will be appreciated.
I have also asked this question on [mathematics stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3810035/analytical-value-of-maxima-for-a-function-involving-logarithm-and-exponential).

Comment: To @Mark Robinson. Have you noticed, that your mathematica code for expr is different from the code given in traditional form at the beginning. Your mathematica code has additional parenthes after the x in numerator, which changes everything!

Comment: @Akku14Mathematica one is correct. Sorry for the typo/mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

expr = (c + 
     x (Log[-2 + 2 E^(c/x)] - Log[-1 + E^((2 c)/x)]))/(x (Log[-1 + E^(c/x)] - 
       Log[-1 + E^((2 c)/x)]));
```

Let z == c/x

```
expr2 = expr /. c -> x*z // Simplify

(* (z + Log[-2 + 2 E^z] - Log[-1 + E^(2 z)])/(Log[-1 + E^z] - Log[-1 + E^(2 z)]) *)
```

The exact minimum of `expr2` with respect to `z` is expressed as [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) expressions

```
min = Minimize[{expr2, z > 0}, z] // FullSimplify

(* {(Log[(1/2)*(1 + E^Root[
                   {Log[2^E^#1*(1 + E^#1)^(-1 - E^#1)] + E^#1*#1 & , 
           1.22480369074195909259830444438144617909`20.60205517313497}])] - 
        Root[{Log[2^E^#1*(1 + E^#1)^(-1 - E^#1)] + E^#1*#1 & , 
      1.22480369074195909259830444438144617909`20.60205517313497}])/
     Log[1 + E^Root[{-((1 + E^#1)*Log[1 + 
                          E^#1]) + E^#1*(Log[2] + #1) & , 
       1.22480369074195909259830444438144617909`20.60205517313497}]], 
   {z -> Root[{-((1 + E^#1)*Log[1 + E^#1]) + E^#1*(Log[2] + #1) & , 
     1.22480369074195909259830444438144617909`20.60205517313497}]}} *)
```

The approximate numeric values are

```
min // N

(* {-0.293815, {z -> 1.2248}} *)

argMin = z /. min[[2]];
```

Verifying,

```
D[expr2, z] == 0 /. z -> argMin // FullSimplify

(* True *)

D[expr2, {z, 2}] > 0 /. z -> argMin // Simplify

(* True *)
```

The minimum is along the line

```
c == x*argMin

(* c == x*Root[
       {-((1 + E^#1)*Log[1 + E^#1]) + E^#1*(Log[2] + #1) & , 
    1.22480369074195909259830444438144617909`20.60205517313497}] *)

Show[
 Plot3D[Evaluate@expr, {x, 0, 3}, {c, 0, 3*argMin},
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5],
  PlotPoints -> 50,
  WorkingPrecision -> 15],
 Graphics3D[{Red, Thick, 
   Evaluate@Line[{{0, 0, min[[1]]}, {3, 3*argMin, min[[1]]}}]}],
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, c, "expr"}),
 PlotLabel -> expr,
 ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]